# How to call a directive from a html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

I have a directive like below,

```
 .directive('lbd', function () {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
          context: '=',
          dui: '='
      },
   }
 });
```

Calling template,

```
     <lbd class="col-xs-12 lbd" context="disease-description" dui="id"></lbd>
```

I am giving id fro my controller as,

```
  $scope.id = "222";
```

But the directive is not rendered.I am not able to find the solution.Can anyone please help me.Thanks.

Comment: you defined the directive as `element directive` but didn't give it a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a mistake in your `directive`. remove `,` after `scope` body.
and `disease-description` should be `=`  scope such as `$scope.id`. 
But i think `disease-description` is as `string` so change `context` type to `@` in directive.

```
 .directive('lbd', function () {
  return {
   restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      context: '@',
      dui: '='
    }
 }
});
```

```js
var app = angular.module('anApp', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.id = "222";
});
 app.directive('lbd', function () {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
          context: '@',
          dui: '='
      },
      template:"<p>{{dui}},{{context}}</p>"
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="anApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
<lbd class="col-xs-12 lbd" context="disease-description" dui="id"></lbd>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Hadi,your code worked greatly,I am reaching my directive but the template is not displayed.

Comment: And that is my css issue.Thanks Hadi.